# Can the infinite jungle gym surface be expressed by an exhaustion of compact surfaces with one boundary component?

Tags: gn.general-topology, gt.geometric-topology, surfaces

Is it possible to write the infinite jungle gym surface as the increasing union of compact surfaces whose boundaries consist of only one simple closed curve? I believe that this is true. This surface has only one end. Therefore the result follows from the existence of canonical exhaustions (made of compact surfaces whose components of the complement have one boundary component) (as explained in Ahlfors-Sario book). If anyone could help me, I would like to "see" such a curve. Thanks.

Comment: The answer to this question is "yes".  This is an example of an "infinite Loch Ness surface"; see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1701.07151.pdf for a discussion of these surfaces and references to the classification of surfaces of infinite type.  All infinite-genus $1$ ended surfaces are diffeomorphic, and thus are diffeomorphic to the canonical example of the union of the genus-$g$ surfaces $\Sigma_{g,1}$ with one boundary component as $g$ goes to infinity (the boundary curves here give you the curves you are looking for).  I'm not a good artist, so I'll leave others to give you explicit pictures.

Comment: (note: I was not the person who downvoted, and in fact haven't registered my account and thus do not have voting rights at all!)

Comment: Consider an exhaustion of this surface by an $n \times n \times n$ "cube" (for each $n$), with $6(n+1)^2$ boundary circles coming from all the "rods" sticking out. Now draw a giant circuituous circle (simple closed curve) on the surface that encloses all these boundary circles.

Comment: Cross-posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070057/can-the-infinite-jungle-gym-surface-be-expressed-by-an-exhaustion-of-compact-sur). In general, you should not post a questions simultaneously here and at MSE.